# Съзжает сайт.Вёрстка под пк

Tags: html, html5, вёрстка

Идёт сдвиг иконок и чекбоксов на мобильной версии с разными разрешениям, и на версии под пк. Необходимо зафиксировать иконки и чекбоксы по центру. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Wi-Fi</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h1>Добро пожаловать в зону бесплатного Wi-Fi</h1>
        <h2>Для доступа в интернет, пройдите авторизацию</h2>   
    <img class="q" src="inst.png">  
    <img class="w" src="vk.png">
    <input style="position: relative; bottom: 28px; left: 9px; size: 10px; transform:scale(1.5); cursor:pointer;" type="checkbox">
        <input style="position: relative; bottom: 28px; left: 120px; size: 10px; transform:scale(1.5); cursor:pointer;" type="checkbox">

<form class="sa" method="post">
    <p class="o" align="center"><input maxlength="14" minlength="9" type="login" name="login"></p>
    <p class="s" align="center"><input maxlength="14" minlength="9" type="password" name="password"></p>
    <p align="center"><input class="btn" type="submit" value="Войти"></p> 
</form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.body.onkeydown = function(e){
e = e || window.event;
var c = e.keyCode;
//Убирает эвент на стрелках, на pageDown, PageUp, Home, End
if(c>36 && c<41 || c>32 && c<37) return false;
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(index.jpeg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: table;
}

.container {
    margin-top: 220px;
}

h1 {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 190px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 150%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;

}

h2 {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 160px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.form {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 30px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
    h1 { font-size: 150%; 
    }

body,html {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.sa {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 50px;
}

input {
    height: 26px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;

}

.btn {
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    height: 40px;
    width: -70px;
}

.q {
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 53px;
    left: 92px;

}

.w {
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 52px;
    left: 180px;
}
```

Comment: это точно вы делали ? если вы то 1000% сможете сделать десктпную версию , если же не вы то отдайте вёрстку тому кто её делал или на фриланс

Comment: Это я делал, но с помощью гугла.

Comment: как это с помощью гугла ?

Comment: Тут проблема в том, что идёт сдвиг одновременно у иконок и чебоксов. Не получается зафиксировать.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Изменил вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Иконки уезжают в сторону, так как отступы указаны в пикселях. Если Вы хотите зафиксировать по центру - задайте иконкам и чекбоксам стили: display: block; margin: 0 auto. И 3-м стилем ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО задайте элементам фиксированную ширину: width: 50px (вместо 50 поставьте подходящее для Вас значение).